# Could not extract native JNI library

Tags: java, android-studio, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create en .apk from the node.js command promt with:

> ionic build android

For some reason I get the: Could not extract native JNI library error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have the 1.8.0._101 of Java installed and the latest Android Studio.

Comment: did u got the solution for this ?

Comment: Yeah, made a clean fresh install of JAVA and all Ionic libraries. Also clean the cache. Also, make sure to use the stable version of node, not the bleeding edge,

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply making a new fresh install of JAVA, cleaning the cache and not using the bleeding-edge version of node.js I solved this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case - just running gradlew from the (windows) commandline - the problem was caused by a setting, probably my `HOME` or `HOMEPATH`, with special characters in it (a double exclamation mark).

And the problem was resolved by adding a line to gradlew.bat, just below the `'set CLASSPATH ...'` line:

```
'set GRADLE_USER_HOME=%APP_HOME%gradle\user'
```