# When i have build ionic app at that time given native Library error. given this below

Tags: java, cordova, ionic2, java-native-interface

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users<user>\android-sdks

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

**What went wrong:
Could not extract native JNI library.**

Advance Thanks for Helping.....

Comment: Sorry in first line path is 

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\user\android-sdks

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621040/could-not-extract-native-jni-library does this work?

Comment: no doesn't work i will try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PLEASE UNINSTALL JAVA AND CLEAR CACHE AFTER THAT INSTALL AGAIN JAVA THEN YOU CAN BUILD YOUR APPLICATION.